Changing kg to lbs in a column in Jupyter Python
DataFrameI have a DataFrame with a column that is currently in kgs. I am trying to convert it to lbs. It is 316 lines and dtype is object. I have tried different approaches:
df["Kerb_Weight"]=df["Kerb_Weight"].str.replace(r'\s[a-z]+$',
df.Kerb_Weight

    
astype().df["Kerb_Weight"]=df["Kerb_Weight"].astype(float)
df.Kerb_Weight



df.Kerb_Weight=df["New_Kerb_Weight"]=df["New_Kerb_Weight"]
.str.replace(r'\sg$|\skg$|\sml$', '')
df.New_Kerb_Weight    


kw=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({df.Kerb_Weight})
df["New_Kerb_Weight"]=df["Kerb_Weight"].str.replace('\d+', '')
print(kw)

Can someone either tell me what I am missing or which approach should be working because I am out of ideas.

Can you fix up the formatting of your code? Adding 4 spaces in front of a line makes it appear as code.

OK I tried to clean it up.

Since we can't see the data in this dataframe, is it that the column has values like 1 kg or 34.4 g and you just want to change it to 1 lb and 34.4 lb. Something like .replace(r'\sg$|\skg$|\sml$', ' lb', regex=True) would work fine. However, I can't help but think you are wanting to also convert the values. Can you explain more with sample data and desired results what you are trying to accomplish.

I did not know I could add pictures on here. Ive added a screenshot of the part of the data that I'm talking about. I am supposed to be able to remove the measurements, kg, and then convert it to pounds and add the measurement lbs. I have tried it different ways and am just lost as to why I cannot make the code do what I am wanting.

If I understand the data and what you want: as you know the value is in kg, you can just extract the value, convert to pounds and change to a string with units. For example:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Kerb_Weight': ['1.25 kg', '24kg', '.56 kg']})

df['val'] = df['Kerb_Weight'].str.extract(r"(\d*\.{0,1}\d*)").astype(float).mul(2.204).round(2)
df['pounds'] = df['val'].astype(str) + ' lbs'

print(df)

gives:
  Kerb_Weight    val    pounds
0     1.25 kg   2.76  2.76 lbs
1        24kg  52.90  52.9 lbs
2      .56 kg   1.23  1.23 lbs


To tackle this you can split out the magnitude from the unit using some regex, then consider using a module like pint to handle unit conversion. A module is nice for this work as it's ready-built code that can handle conversion from any unit to any other unit so you don't have to juggle a bunch of conversion values.
Consider:
import pandas as pd 
from pint import UnitRegistry

ureg=UnitRegistry()

#make a dataframe with an id and weight in kgs including the unit
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3,4],"weight":['113455 grams','2462316 mg','3 slug','4 kg']})

#assuming the format of weight is always <number><space character><unit>
# split to new columns using extract()
df[['weight','unit']]=df['weight'].str.extract(pat=r'(.*)\s(.*)')

#Create a convert function for the `df.apply()`. 
# This function will take in a weight and unit 
# and convert it to the requested output unit 
# using the pint module imported above
def convert(weight ,unit, out_unit):
    inval = ureg.Quantity(int(weight), unit)
    outval = inval.to(out_unit)
    return outval.magnitude, outval.units

#df apply to convert function to convert every weight/unit pair to pounds
df[['converted_weight','converted_unit']] = df.apply(lambda x: convert(x.weight,x.unit,'pound'), axis=1, result_type="expand")

display(df)


+-----+----+---------+-------+------------------+----------------+
| idx | id | weight  | unit  | converted_weight | converted_unit |
+-----+----+---------+-------+------------------+----------------+
|   0 |  1 |  113455 | grams |       250.125460 | pound          |
|   1 |  2 | 2462316 | mg    |         5.428478 | pound          |
|   2 |  3 |       3 | slug  |        96.522146 | pound          |
|   3 |  4 |       4 | kg    |         8.818490 | pound          |
+-----+----+---------+-------+------------------+----------------+

